# Chrome on new Windows install will not sync

Tags: google-chrome, sync, bookmarks

I just upgraded my Desktop to Windows 10.  Chrome will not sync.  I've logged out and back in a couple times and also installed the beta channel.  It still will not sync.  When I go to `chrome://sync` it shows "Last Synced: Just Now".  I have no bookmarks, themes, passwords, history or anything.  I have set it to sync nothing, everything and all individual items in between.  Still no luck.

Here is the sync protocol log

```
5/9/2016, 12:43:12 PM Commit Request
Item count: 1
Contributing types: Sessions
5/9/2016, 12:43:12 PM Commit Response
Result: SYNCER_OK
5/9/2016, 12:43:35 PM Normal GetUpdate request
Notified types: Search Engines
5/9/2016, 12:43:35 PM GetUpdates Response
Received 13 update(s).
```

When I look at my dashboard (https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync) it shows everything I would expect.

Sync seems to be working fine on my work laptop and my home laptop.

Currently I'm using Version 51.0.2704.36 beta-m (64-bit)

[image]

Comment: Most obvious solution would be the value of a conflicting group policy.

Comment: We have no Active Directory, no group policy.  This is not work related.  THis could just as easily be my personal machine.  As I mentioned in the question, Chrome Sync works fine on my work laptop.  It also worked on my desktop before it was upgraded to Windows 10.

Comment: You are using the beta version of Chrome, does the production version sync or is that also exhibiting the same behaviour?

Comment: Did a fresh install today on a new laptop and am having the same issue. Something is screwy on Google's end.

Comment: @Burgi yes, i tried stable first, beta in the hopes that it would work

Comment: This appears to be resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not alone. A lot of people are experiencing similar problem. Seems the problem is on Google's side.
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/xFikeY7GOu0

Comment: FYI this appears to have been resolved.  Without changing anything, around 9:00 this morning, everything magically synced.